# Is there an Ionic Features Demo App for Android/iOS?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have looked around, but cannot find an Ionic features demo on the Google Play Store, or any mention of one. There are the Showcase Apps, but most of these mention that they used Ionic, but also had to do bespoke development to get them to be truly cross platform. There are user submitted Ionic demo apps on PlayStore, but they are dreadful, if they even load or work at all.

It's weird that a mobile framework & platform company do not have a demo mobile app with their framework's features .... but I'm still hoping to find one! Any ideas?

P.S. I'm aware that there are github demos I can download, build, deploy, and run.... but that is a tad ridiculous when I just want to see the thing running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked in the Ionic Slack and there are *no* apps like this. (No official ones that is.) So yeah, "No" is your answer.

Comment: Err... so are you implying they don't want to people to see it perform badly? Maybe I'm misreading you. If not - I can say that Ionic folks have spent a *lot* of time on performance tuning.

Comment: Thanks, that's a pretty straightforward answer:-)